# New home owner with water problem

Tags: flooding

Our house was built in the the 80s, and sometime after that they converted the garage into a new living space, and added a new garage.  I live below a flood plain, and have water coming into the house from multiple points.  I do not know how to begin, or who to call.  The leaks at the front of the house are at points below ground level, and the leaks at the back are higher than where the water pools up.  Overall my entire backyard pretty much becomes a lake.  Thanks in advance for any help someone can provide, and if someone needs more info to help narrow down my problem I will answer to the best of my ability.

Comment: Seems like a major ground water/drainage problem.  How often does this “water pooling” occur?   Did any of the home inspectors make notes about previous flooding or water damage?

Comment: That was our original thought, and the entire yard floods quite a bit.  The only issue is that the pooling is not near the areas where the water comes in the house.  I have a landscaping company coming to look into drainage.  The one thing I am noticing is that the wall connecting the house to the old garage/current living room is where the water is coming in from.